Continue after catch
I have the following block of code. I want to continue after running a function in the catch block. I know it's not possible this way, I'm just wondering if there is a way to dot source or some other trick to make it work.
code:
Function Get-LatestEdgeWebDriver {

  $modpath = (join-path -path ($env:PSModulePath -split ';')[0] -ChildPath 'Selenium\3.0.1\assemblies')
  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $modpath -ChildPath 'edgedriver_win64.zip'
  Set-Location $modpath

  $EdgeExe = Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\msedge.exe' "(default)"
  $version = (Get-Item $EdgeExe).VersionInfo.ProductVersion
  $download = 'https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net/' + $version + '/edgedriver_win64.zip'
  $web_request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $download
  if(($web_request.Content[0] -is [byte]) -and $web_request.StatusCode -eq 200){
    if ($PSversiontable.psversion.major -eq 7) {
      Set-Content -Path $filepath -asBytestream -Value $web_request.Content -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
    } else {Set-Content -Path $filepath -Encoding Byte -Value $web_request.Content -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force}
  }

  Load-Module '7Zip4Powershell'
  Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName .\edgedriver_win64.zip -TargetPath . 
  Start-Sleep -seconds 5
  if((Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'MicrosoftWebDriver'} | Measure-object).Count -gt 0)
  {Get-Process -name MicrosoftWebDriver | kill -Force}
  Move-Item -Path .\msedgedriver.exe -Destination .\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe -Force
  Remove-Item -Path .\edgedriver_win64.zip -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  Set-Location $scriptpath
  write-host -ForegroundColor yellow "Edge Webdriver Updated to $version version.."
}


# Code starts here

# More code here

try {
      $Driver = Start-SeEdge -StartURL $uri -PrivateBrowsing -Quiet -Minimized -WarningVariable $warn -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
      Enter-SeUrl $uri -Driver $Driver -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
    }catch {[System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException]{
        write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Old version of Edgedriver found. updating... "
        Get-LatestEdgeWebDriver
        # Continue out of catch
        }
    }

# continue code below this line


But that's exactly what happens. The code continues running after the catch block. Whatever code you write the down there will continue to run. Now, if you mean you want it to resume from where it left off inside whatever method was running before the exception was raised, that will NOT happen, because it is widely considered a foolish thing to do. What you might do instead is use a LOOP to run again from further up, with a line of code at the end of the try block to set a flag so the loop will exit.
